# Calling JS from html.actionlink with passing a parameter

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

i have this line:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Group", "Recommend", new { area = "User" , groupId = item.GroupId, onclick = "Approve(<% groupId %>)" } ) %>
```

and need to pass groupId to the JS function Approve(<% groupId %>)
the line gives an error: NewLine in constant. the second %> is highlighted in yellow but not the first one in Approve(<% groupId %>). do i have missing tags or missing a quote?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Group", "Recommend", new %>
<%: { %>
        area = "User" , 
        groupId = item.GroupId, 
        onclick = "Approve(" + item.GroupId + ")" 
<%: } ) %>
```

Comment: thanks here is my line now: <%: Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Group", "Recommend", new { area = "User", groupId = item.GroupId, onclick = "Approve(" + item.GroupId + ")" }) %>